# How to get a number of elements of a dynamic object returned by Enumerable.Except()?

Tags: c#, reflection, dynamic, collections

How do i get the number of elements of a dynamic object returned by Enumerable.Except()?

Look:

```
dynamic itensToRemove = Enumerable.Except(currentCollection, newCollection);
dynamic itensToAdd = Enumerable.Except(newCollection, currentCollection);
```

When i try to do this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < itensToRemove.Count(); i++)
```

I got the runtime error 'object does not contain a definition for Count', so, how i can i got the number of elements?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`dynamic` doesn't resolve extension methods, which is why you've explicitly got calls to `Enumerable.Except`. Do the same thing for `Count`:

```
// You don't want to do this on every iteration!
int count = Enumerables.Count(itemsToRemove);
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
```

It's not clear why you'd want to use that in a `for` loop though - it would be more normal to use it in a `foreach` loop. You may also want to consider using `ToList` to make sure you evaluate the query *once*:

```
dynamic itemsToRemoveList = Enumerable.ToList(itemsToRemove);
```

Comment: Hmmm, now i'm getting that. Do you have a good reference to learning about dynamic elements?

Comment: Because i have to remove the itens, and when i use foreach the loop throws a error that the collection was modified.

Comment: @ViniciusOttoni: C# in Depth has a chapter about dynamic typing :) But using a `for` loop here is a bad idea. You haven't shown what you're removing from, but there's bound to be a better way of approaching it.